# How to execute an inner class inside of Class which accessed from adapter inside of Class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a problem with access an Asynctask<> which inside of A class and A class have a adapter (RecyclerViewAdapter) which wanted to access the class which extends the Asynctask<>

for short, it'd be like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SimpleRecyclerAdapter simpleRecyclerAdapter;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(SimpleRecyclerAdapter);

    public class getData extends AsyncTask<>{
        ....
    }
}
```

and this is the SimpleRecyclerAdapter

```
public class SimpleRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleRecyclerAdapter.VersionViewHolder> {

//from this I would like to execute getData class

}
```

Comment: class name should be capital...change that first.

Comment: I am guessing your asynctask is used to get some data which in turn would give results to be populated in your adapter. In which case, its better to wait for the result of the asynctask and then use the result to populate your adapter. Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: Create an Interface.And call getData.execute on it's callback.

Comment: Mochamad Lucky Pradana : Try my post it will definitely  work in any case with out loading your device

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya answer is correct .That is the right way to go..

Comment: sunil sunny : Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
RecyclerView recyclerView;
SimpleRecyclerAdapter simpleRecyclerAdapter;
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
new GetData().execute();



}


public class SimpleRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleRecyclerAdapter.VersionViewHolder> {

 //from this I would like to execute getData class

}

public class GetData extends AsyncTask<>{
   @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
         recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleRecyclerAdapter());
    }
}
```